# Пропал код формы C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Не помню, после чего такое произошло, но исчез код `Form1.cs`.

- Form1.resx (код есть)
- Form1.Designer.cs (код есть)

А вот `Form1.cs исчез`: точнее, он по-прежнему занимает 30Кб, но при просмотре все символы стали пробелами.

Сама `Visual Studio` выдает:

> There is no editor available for
>   '....path....\Form1.cs'.
>
> Make sure the application for the file
>   type (.cs) is installed.

Другие формы открываются как по маслу. Какие могут быть варианты решения?

Comment: Откройте блокнотом и посмотрите содержимое файла Form1.cs . Если с ним всё в порядке, то сохраните резервную копию папки проекта со всеми файлами и переустановите VS.

Comment: В этом-то и дело, я бы с удовольствием, но открываю и вместо кода сплошные пробелы на 30 Кб